# How to increase the height of the Arrowed Progress bar CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement an Arrowed Progress bar, I'm facing a CSS error. When I increase the height of content the appended arrows don't increase in their height.
Try to run the code spinnet and you will understand the error I'm facing. The error is based on CSS and triangle/arrow progress bar content height

```css
ol.steps {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Liberation Sans', Verdana, 'Verdana Ref', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  counter-reset: li;
}

ol.steps li {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  background: #dae4eb;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 43px;
}

ol.steps li:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 100%;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #dae4eb;
  border-width: 19px;
  margin-top: -19px;
}

ol.steps li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

ol.steps li:first-child span {
  padding: 9px;
}

ol.steps li:first-child span:after {
  border: none;
}

ol.steps li:last-child:after {
  border-width: 0;
}

ol.steps li span {
  display: block;
  padding: 9px 28px 9px 9px;
}

ol.steps li span:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: solid #dae4eb;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-width: 19px;
  margin-top: -19px;
}

ol.steps li span:before {
  content: counter(li) " ";
  counter-increment: li;
}

ol.steps>li {
  float: left;
}

ol.steps li.current {
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0078b4;
}

ol.steps li.current:after {
  border-left-color: #0078b4;
}

ol.steps li.current span:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

ol.steps li.step1 {
  z-index: 9;
}

ol.steps li.step2 {
  z-index: 8;
}

ol.steps li.step3 {
  z-index: 7;
}

ol.steps li.step4 {
  z-index: 6;
}

ol.steps li.step5 {
  z-index: 5;
}

ol.steps li.step6 {
  z-index: 4;
}

ol.steps li.step7 {
  z-index: 3;
}

ol.steps li.step8 {
  z-index: 2;
}

ol.steps li.step9 {
  z-index: 1;
}

ol.steps li.step10 {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol class="steps">
  <li class="step1 current"><span><br>Submitted</span></li>
  <li class="step2"><span><br>.</span></li>
  <li class="step3"><span><br>.</span></li>
  <li class="step4"><span><br>.</span></li>
  <li class="step5"><span><br>.</span></li>
</ol>
```

Error image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYf8i.png)

I Tried many CSS tweaks but dint succeed in matching the heights

Comment: Hi. You should edit your question to meet the standards of how to ask a question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Dejan.S I did, can you please check it now